VARIABLES EN FUNCION FPDF
estoy desarrollando una idea  de facturación digital y creo los pdf usando tfpdf para manejar fuentes personalizadas
estoy usando una clase para agregar una marca de agua y funciona muy bien solo que me gustaría logar que los valores  fueran manejables desde el frontend.


$header = mysqli_query($conexion, "
SELECT c.*,
f.nombre_fuente AS nombre_familia,
f.nombre_archivo AS archivo_fuente
FROM configuracion_pdf c
LEFT JOIN fuentes f ON c.fuente_wt = f.fuente_id
WHERE c.en_uso = 1
");

if ($header && $wt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($header)) {
    $nombreFamilia = $wt['nombre_familia'];
    $archivoFuente = $wt['archivo_fuente'];
  $estilo =$wt['estilo_wt'];
  $tamano =$wt['tamano_wt'];


} else {
    die("Error: No se pudo obtener la configuración del encabezado.");
}


class PDF extends PDF_Rotate
{
    public $nombreFamilia;
    public $archivoFuente;
    public $estilo;
    public $tamano;
     
function Header()
{

    $this->AddFont('Collegiateflf','','Collegiateflf.ttf',true);
    $this->SetFont('Collegiateflf','',90);
    $this->SetTextColor(193, 193, 190);
    $this->RotatedText(40,210,'DUPLICADO',45);
}

function RotatedText($x, $y, $txt, $angle)
{
    //Text rotated around its origin
    $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
    $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
    $this->Rotate(0);
}
}



el asunto que se me presenta de manera negativa es que al pasar las variables $nombreFamilia, $archivoFuente, $estilo, $tamano me llegan como NULL
Lo sé porque he colocado un vardump


       function Header()
{
   
    var_dump($this->nombreFamilia);
    var_dump($this->archivoFuente);
    var_dump($this->estilo);
    var_dump($this->tamano);

    // Configuración de la fuente y texto no funciona porque las variables son NULL
    $this->AddFont($this->nombreFamilia, '',  $this->archivoFuente, true);
    $this->SetFont($this->nombreFamilia, $this->estilo, $this->tamano);
    $this->SetTextColor(193, 193, 190);
    $this->RotatedText(40, 210, 'DUPLICADO', 45);
}
    



y el volcado me regresa como NULL todas las variables, ya use echo para los resultados de la base de datos y todos vienen correctamente
me pueden ayudar por favor

Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué significa querer que los valores fueran manejables desde el frontend? Por otra parte, para hacer con una clase algo del tipo $this->nombreFamilia tú debes primero instanciar esa clase y asignarle un valor a la propiedad nombreFamilia y a las demás propiedades, sean en el constructor o de otro modo. ¿Dónde estás instanciando la clase y asignado las propiedades?

Hay afirmaciones confusas en tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, no se entiende qué significa querer que los valores fueran manejables desde el frontend.
En cuanto al error, que mencionas, para hacer con una clase algo del tipo $this->nombreFamilia tú debes primero instanciar esa clase y asignarle un valor a la propiedad nombreFamilia y a las demás propiedades, sea en el constructor o de otro modo.
El lugar adecuado para hacer eso, sería donde obtienes los datos que van destinados a la clase, que supongo será cuando haces la consulta a la base de datos.
Dado que mysqli ofrece la posibilidad de informar las propiedades de una clase mediante el método fetch_object(), podemos aprovechar eso para quitar verbosidad al código. El único inconveniente es que para que funcione los nombres de columna deben coincidir con los nombres de propiedades de la clase, pero eso lo podemos revolver relativamente fácil usando alias  en la instrucción SQL.
El código quedaría así:
$header = mysqli_query($conexion, "
SELECT 
  f.nombre_fuente AS nombreFamilia,
  f.nombre_archivo AS archivoFuente,
  c.estilo_wt AS estilo,
  c.tamano_wt AS tamano
FROM configuracion_pdf c
LEFT JOIN fuentes f ON c.fuente_wt = f.fuente_id
WHERE c.en_uso = 1
");

if ($header && $wt = mysqli_fetch_object($header,'PDF')) {
    /*
       En este contexto, $wt será una instancia 
       de tu clase PDF, con las propiedades debidamente asignadas
       haremos un var_dump de prueba
       Ahora puedes emitir un documento PDF o lo que necesites
    */
     var_dump($wt);    
} else {
    die("Error: No se pudo obtener la configuración del encabezado.");
}

